# Python install xmlrpclib

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, virtualenv

I'm in a virtualenv and trying to run a script I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "blah.py", line 15, in <module>
    from xmlrpc import server
ImportError: No module named xmlrpc
```

Ok so that seems that I need xmlrpc, which I'm assuming means I need xmlrpclib

So I try that:

```
(env) ❯❯❯ pip2.7 install xmlrpclib                                                                
Collecting xmlrpclib
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement xmlrpclib (from versions: )
  Some externally hosted files were ignored as access to them may be unreliable (use --allow-external xmlrpclib to allow).
No matching distribution found for xmlrpclib
```

Ok, so then I'll try the --allow-external to get it working:

```
(env) ❯❯❯ pip2.7 install --allow-external xmlrpclib                                                                                                                           ⏎ ◼
You must give at least one requirement to install (see "pip help install")
```

Not sure why xmlrpclib isn't seen to be a valid argument?

Comment: **pip command package additional argument**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is that the module `xmlrpc` is part of python3, not python2.x

details: https://docs.python.org/3/library/xmlrpc.server.html

Should already be installed, just go ahead and use it.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if `pip` provides this lib. Just download `xmlrpclib` from here http://effbot.org/downloads/#xmlrpclib, unpack it and then run:

```
python3 setup.py build
python3 setup.py install
```

Comment: After installing I am getting the error File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/xmlrpclib.py", line 169
    MAXINT =  2L**31-1
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I am not a python programmer, I trying to execute an application which was written in python

Answer (score 2):

If you are using python 2.x then `xmlrpclib` is part of standard lib. No need of installing it.

Anyway you can download xmlrpclib from [http://effbot.org](http://effbot.org/media/downloads/tkicon-0.9-19980218.win32-py2.1.exe)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer to your question can be [found here](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/1423).

Try adding `--allow-unverified` to your last command.

**EDIT:** I think your import statement is wrong. The module is called `xmlrpclib`, not `xmlrpc`

Comment: This is what I'm confused about, I'm not sure is there is an xmlrpc module and was hoping that the xmlrpclib module would somehow provide what this one is doing (I didn't write the script)

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to use the correct interpreter. xmlrpc is part of python3, using python3 interpreter.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, but this information was already provided in the accepted answer. Please avoid posting duplicate answers.